# Match data between two csv files and replace data

Tags: python, list, csv, file-read

I have two csv files. 
First is like

```
a, right 
b, something 
c, right
d, something
```

Second file

```
b,  wrong 
e, something 
a,  wrong 
d, something
```

I want output like

```
b, right 
e,  something 
a, right
d, something
```

I have tried this code

```
import csv

f1 = open("file1.csv")
f2 = open("file2.csv")

csv_f1 = csv.reader(f1)
csv_f2 = csv.reader(f2)

for row1 in csv_f1: 
    for row2 in csv_f2:
        if row1[0] == row2[0]:
            print row1[0], row1[1]
        else:
            print row2[0], row2[1]
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but the way you phrase your question is very confusing - I can't understand what exactly your expected inputs and outputs are supposed to be. Can you edit your post to make it more clear what the format of the files and output are supposed to be - perhaps by pasting a few lines of each file into your question?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am iterating from one file to another. Checking if row1[0] is equal to row2[0] and replacing wrong value with right. File 1 has correct value of corresponding value of row[0]

Comment: What is the algorithm here? Are you want to take all first elements from second file and combine with all second elements from first file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly. You need to compare the csvs line by line.

In that case you can use `zip` in `pythoonic` way

For loop looks like below

```
for row1, row2 in zip(csv_f1, csv_f2):
```

Full code

```
import csv

f1 = open("file1.csv")
f2 = open("file2.csv")

csv_f1 = csv.reader(f1)
csv_f2 = csv.reader(f2)

for row1, row2 in zip(csv_f1, csv_f2): 
    if row1[0] == row2[0]:
        print(row1[0], row1[1])
    else:
        print(row2[0], row2[1])
```

By the way. It is in `python3`. You seem to be using `python2`

With zip_longest

```
import csv, itertools

f1 = open("file1.csv")
f2 = open("file2.csv")

csv_f1 = csv.reader(f1)
csv_f2 = csv.reader(f2)

for row1, row2 in itertools.zip_longest(csv_f1, csv_f2, fillvalue=[0, 0]):
    if row1[0] == row2[0]:
        print(row1[0], row1[1])
    else:
        print(row2[0], row2[1])
```

Comment: Does it work if first file has less number of rows than second file.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip  says ...The iterator stops when the shortest input iterable is exhausted...

Comment: bro script stooped at row 8900 .it should go to all rows which is arround 100000 .first file is small 8900 rows second file has aprox 100000 so script should iterate to all rows and print all 100000 rows .

Comment: Try itertools.zip_longest

Comment: How? please describe with some example. If you can give working code that will be highly appreciated

Comment: Updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: Thank you very much bro